# setOnFocusChangeListener not working when add TextView programmatically

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I can't set `setOnFocusChangeListener` or even `setOnClickListener` when I try to add a textview programmatically.

I tried

```
txt1.requestFocus();
txt1.setFocusable(true);
txt1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

and

```
txt1.setClickable(true);
```

`setOnTouchListener` is working but the other listeners doesn't.
This my code:

```
text_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        try 
        {
            TextView txt1 = new TextView(DashActivity.this);

            txt1.setText("This is me");
            txt1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
            txt1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAC421"));
            txt1.requestFocus();
            txt1.setFocusable(true);
            txt1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            txt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Log.i("txt: ", "Clicked");
                    } 
                    catch (NullPointerException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            txt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
                {
                    Log.i("txt:" , "Changed");

                    if(hasFocus)
                    {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_border);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    }
                }
            });

            txt1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) 
                    {
                            // Offsets are for centering the TextView on the touch location
                        v.setX(event.getRawX());
                        v.setY(event.getRawY());
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

            mRrootLayout.addView(txt1);
        } 
        catch (NullPointerException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` instead of `true` in `onTouch` method in `View.OnTouchListener`. When you return true, you mark this touch event as handled, so this touch event isn't propagate further (to OnClickListener and OnFocusChangeListener).